# Run a docker container inside Gitlab Shared Runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

I am trying to run a docker container with the mongo image inside my .gitlab-ci.yml file. Some of my python files talk to a mongo db. Here is what my .gitlab-ci.yml looks like:

```
default:
  image: python:3.10

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

services:
  - docker:dind

test-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    # install virtualenv (installs into /usr/local/bin)
    - pip3 install virtualenv
    # create virtual env
    - virtualenv venv
    # activate it
    - source venv/bin/activate
    # install necessary packages into virtual env
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt

    # Need to download docker, otherwise get a docker: command not found error
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker.io

    # Run the mongo container
    - docker run -d --name mongo-container mongo:latest
    - python -m pytest tests/
```

However, I am getting a `docker: error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/containers/create?name=mongo_": dial tcp 198.82.184.81:2375: connect: no route to host.` with this.

Does anyone have any advice on where to go with this?
Thank you

Comment: I think what you're probably looking for is to run `mongo:latest` as the service instead of this docker-in-docker setup with `docker:dind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider instantiating the mongo database as your gitlab service instead of using `docker:dind`. This will create the mongo container for you in parallel with your main (python) container, which can then interact with the mongo container via the pymongo library.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**:

```yaml
stages:
  - test

variables:
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "admin"
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"

services:
  - name: mongo:4
    alias: mongodb

test:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.11
  before_script:
    - python -m ensurepip
    - pip install pymongo
  script:
    - python example.py
```

**example.py**:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Connect to host "mongodb" (alias of the gitlab service) at default port (27017)
client = MongoClient("mongodb", 27017)

# Interact with the DB
db = client["my_database"]
collection = db["my_collection"]
```